# Use latex code in math expression in Lyx

Tags: beamer, math-mode, lyx

I would like to enter the expression

```
\textcolor<2>{red}{stuff}
```

inside a Lyx math environment. But Lyx always renders it as

```
\textcolor{}<2>{red}{stuff}
```

Is there a way how to pass `<>` arguments to Lyx in mathmode?

Comment: The syntax is not correct, `\color` does only take one argument, the colour. Try `\textcolor<2>{red}{stuff}`

Comment: are you sure? in beamer documentclass it works for me... either case, the same question applies to \textcolor<2>{red}{stuff}. How can I get Lyx to pass <2> as an argument in math mode?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Try `\color<2>{red}{stuff} other stuff` and have a look what happens to the "other stuff", it will also be red. If you want to use `\color`, you can do it like this: `{\color{red} stuff} other stuff`

Comment: fair enough, I'll edit my original question. But still, the question was not really about the precise syntax of color, but about how to get Lyx to interpret latex code involving <> inside its mathmode correctly.

Comment: I tried a bit but I'm not even able to insert free tex-code (with ctrl+l) in a equation (and I again know why I don't use lyx, randomlessly clicking around in the hope to find something that works is not to my liking). If you know how to insert code there, you could define yourself a new command `\newcommand\mytextcolor[1]{\textcolor<#1>}` and then use `\mytextcolor{2}{red}{stuff}`

Comment: Great idea! Inserting code without the <> is straightforward, even in math mode, so this should work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how to insert code in a equation in Lyx, you could define yourself a new command

```
 \newcommand\mytextcolor[1]{\textcolor<#1>}
```

and then use

```
 \mytextcolor{2}{red}{stuff}
```

in the equation. This will avoid that Lyx sees the `<>`.